# SQL Server Docker container immediately exiting

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am trying to run a SQL Server container on my mac through Docker.

I ran the following command:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=strongpassword" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlservercontainer -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

But the container is immediately exiting.

The docker logs for the container look like this:

```
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

This container is running as user mssql.

To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.

SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

This container is running as user mssql.

To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.

/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Error: The system directory [/.system] could not be created. File: LinuxDirectory.cpp:420 [Status: 0xC0000022 Access Denied errno = 0xD(13) Permission denied]

/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Error: The system directory [/.system] could not be created. File: LinuxDirectory.cpp:420 [Status: 0xC0000022 Access Denied errno = 0xD(13) Permission denied]
```

Any idea what needs to be done to solve this?

Comment: Did the command you use include a volume mapping? There isn't one in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `sudo` command to create a folder outside of your home directory structure for use by Docker then that folder is going to be owned by the `root` user, e.g.:

```bash
$ sudo mkdir /var/mssql-data

$ ls -la /var/mssql-data
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64B 26 May 11:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x  30 root  wheel   960B 26 May 11:31 ../
```

When you try to launch an SQL Server container using a volume mapping with that folder the container will fail to start - because the Docker backend process doesn't have access - and you will see the "system directory could not be created" error message, e.g.:

```bash
$ docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=StrongPassw0rd" -p 1433:1433 -v /var/mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql --name sqlservercontainer -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
9d6bf76a91af08329ea07fafb67ae68410d5320d9af9db3b1bcc8387821916da

$ docker logs 9d6bf76a91af08329ea07fafb67ae68410d5320d9af9db3b1bcc8387821916da
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Error: The system directory [/.system] could not be created. File: LinuxDirectory.cpp:420 [Status: 0xC0000022 Access Denied errno = 0xD(13) Permission denied]
```

To correct the situation you need to give your own account access to the folder and then a container using that volume mapping will start successfully:

```bash
$ sudo chown $USER /var/mssql-data

$ docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=StrongPassw0rd" -p 1433:1433 -v /var/mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql --name sqlservercontainer -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
3b6634f234024e07af253e69f23971ab3303b3cb6b7bc286463e196dae4de82e
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that this command works for me, here is why:

```
chown 10001:10001 <mount directory of /var/opt/mssql>
```

the **uid** and **gid** `10001` most likely won't be mapped to anything in yout host, but it will be mapped to `mssql` user inside the official container, here is one line of the `passwd` file from the image:

```
mssql:x:10001:10001::/home/mssql:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am running the SQL server 2022 container on WSL2 - Ubuntu 22.04 and I need to fix the root level of the mapped directory to 775 ( or higher 777  )

```
 docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=your_sa_pwd" -p 1433:1433 --name gutlo-sql -h gutlo-sql -v /data/mssql22:/var/opt/mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

$ ls -lad /data/mssql22/
drwxrwxr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 22 18:23 /data/mssql22/
```

And the logs - on a clean new directory, seeding the database

```
 $ docker logs gutlo-sql
SQL Server 2022 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
... ( lines skipped )
2023-06-22 22:23:22.30 spid26s     Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chown 10001:10001 <mount folder>
```

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/735

Comment: Please explain (in the answer) *why* this helps an how it improves a similar suggestion in the accepted answer. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, not an answers store.

Answer (score 0):

everyone

As i am running with compose=>Dockerfile and not mounting anything, was strange to me this error when a i read your comments.
But what solved to me was set on Dockerfile User 10001:
docker-compose.yaml:

bd:

```
    build: pdvbd
    user: root
    command: "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & | grep -q \"Service Broker manager has started\"  "
    ports:
      - "1431:1431"
      - "1433:1433"
      - "1434:1434"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=abcDEF123#
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433
EXPOSE 1431
EXPOSE 1433
EXPOSE 1434
WORKDIR /src
USER 10001
RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && ./init.sh
```

What really solved ?
On Dockerfile set the line USER 10001
Hope this help somebody.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having this issue with docker on Synology, SSH into your Synology and update the permissions to your mounted folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34038874)