# Error container exited -1 after docker run, creating a folder as administrator

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker, containers

I have the same problem of this guys: [SQL Server Docker container immediately exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72383490/sql-server-docker-container-immediately-exiting)

I used this command docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password' --name sqlserver -p 1433:1433 -v /Filippo/data:/var/opt/mssql/data -v /Filippo/log:/var/opt/mssql/log -v /Filippo/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

Where Filippo is my home directory, but then I noticed that I have to create a home directory folder with sudo and assign that folder to my container, the problem is that i'm on Windows.

How can I create a folder as administrator on Windows?

PS: I have created the new folder but when I use docker run the container exits anyway with "Error 1"

Comment: Are you sure your home directory is `/Filippo` in Windows - as opposed to `C:\Users\Filippo`? Are you executing `docker run` from a Command Prompt or PowerShell window? Or from an Ubuntu window under WSL? The point of the answer on the linked question is that the folders you want to use for volumes **cannot** be owned by the `root` account (or SYSTEM on Windows), they have to be owned by your own user account so that Docker Desktop's backend process can access them.

Comment: idk somehow it worked,, i followed the microsoft guide at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Comment: But I have a question , how can I get the connection string from the container that i've just reated?

Comment: Well your publish parameter was `-p 1433:1433` which means you should be able to use `server=tcp:localhost,1433;...` in your connection strings. Or `server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;...` if localhost is somehow defaulting to an IPv6 address.

Comment: this is the last thing that i want to ask, idk if I have to ask in another question.

But is possible to use k8s on visual studio ?